# Need small adjustments to website - MouseOver and Visibility

Tags: jquery, html, css

Visit the http://voorwaartsmarscoaching.nl/ . Click on 1 of the 4 big cubes. The 4 cubes will become small and move to the header. On `MouseOver` on one of the small cubes you will see a text at the right side of the cube. This text must remain visible for the active screen.

EXAMPLE: if a visitor is visiting 'Contact&Referenties', the text 'Contact&Referenties' at the right side of the small cube must remain visible all the time.

please help

**JS**

```
$( ".cube" ).mouseenter(function(){
if( $(this).data("status") == "tiny" ) {
infoId = $(this).attr("id");
$('#info-' + infoId).fadeIn('slow');
}
 });

$( ".cube" ).mouseleave(function(){
    if( $(this).data("status") == "tiny" ) {
    infoId = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#info-' + infoId).show(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: are the top 4 cubes supposed to be evenly distributed across the top?
Each tooltip appears behind the boxes so it cannot be seen properly, fiddle with the Z-index to push this up top?

Comment: did you use the z-index in the css? or did you try to hide the cube at the moment the text is shown?
Some source could help.

Comment: Please  fix box position beacse it shows different position in mozilla and chrom.

Comment: The corresponding blocklabel should get some sort of "active state". So when main content div has "display: block", label of small block should be active and set to display: block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in your code:

**JS**:

```
$(document).on("click", ".cube", function() {
              var  infoId = $(this).attr("id");
              $('#info-' + infoId).show();
});
```

Comment: i need to this same for smartphone. can u help me ?

Comment: Is that site responsive design...? t

Comment: yes it is responsive design

Comment: then it will work..what is the problem you are getting in smartphone..? touch event not happening...?

Comment: The OnmouseOver-text for the small cubes do not appear at the right position on smartphones

Comment: In id contentWrapper inside div position are specified in px ,that's why not showing,try to make in %, #info-uberuns {
left: 22%;
z-index: 100;
} #info-consultant {
left: 42%;
z-index: 100;
} #info-projekte {
left: 62%;
z-index: 100;
}#info-kontakt {
left: 82%;
z-index: 100;
}

Comment: by doing in %. it will display?

Comment: changed into %. But still it is not displaying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44674/discussion-between-manoj-and-developer)